# Object.keys - Element has type "any" implicitly in Typescript

Tags: typescript, object

I have a function to obtain the key having the value of the property. When replicating this function in Typescript I get the following error:

```
The element implicitly has type "any" because the expression of type "any" cannot be used to index the type "TestModel"
```

This is my function:

```
interface TestModel {
    test: string,
    "test 1": string,
    data: string,
    "data 1": string
  }

getKeyByValue(value: string) {

        let data: TestModel = {
            test: "test",
            "test 1": "one Test",
            data: "data",
            "data 1": "one data"
        }

        return Object.keys(data).find((key: any) => data[key] === value);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

New function:

```
return Object.keys(data).find((key: string) => data[key] === value);
```

Error:

```
let data: TestModel
The element implicitly has type "any" because the expression of type "string" cannot be used to index the type "TestModel".
   No index signature found with a parameter of type "string" on type "TestModel"
```

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar That doesn't change anything, I've already tried it. The error occurs in `data[key]`

Comment: A type assertion is one way of doing it. Alternatively, you can put additional constraints on `TestModel` to define the key type, e.g. `interface TestModel extends Record<string, string> {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use explicit `any` type for key. TS is able to figure out that type of `key` is string. However, we know that type of `key` is `keyof TestModel`.

`Object.keys` always returns `string[]` instead of `keyof T` - this is by design, for safety reasons. Hence the most common way in typescript is to use `type assertion` in this case:

```js
interface TestModel {
    test: string,
    "test 1": string,
    data: string,
    "data 1": string
}

class Foo  {

    getKeyByValue(value: string) {

        let data: TestModel = {
            test: "test",
            "test 1": "one Test",
            data: "data",
            "data 1": "one data"
        }

        return (
            (Object.keys(data) as Array<keyof TestModel>)
                .find((key) => data[key] === value)
        );
    }
}
```

You can find more information in [my article](https://catchts.com/union-array)

Comment: Excuse me, I haven't been developing in Typescript for a long time, what does `Array<keyof TestModel>` do? I understand that the typing function is already done by TestModel, right?

Comment: I just saw the article you posted, I'm going to read it, thanks

Comment: Please see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html)